# How to insert a button in MS Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, vba

Friends I am using MS Excel 2010 and  I wish to insert a button in Excel sheet whose name should be ‘1 ADDER’ and I want that whenever I press this button, it should insert 1 in the cell of column A whose front cell was selected before. For example If cell no D8 is selected and I press this button then it should insert 1 in cell no A8. Similarly if cell no Q12 is selected and I press button this button then it should insert 1 in cell no A12. I looked in developer menu in excel to do the same. There is insert button which allows to insert buttons, check boxes, combo boxes and other things, but I do not know how to use them…so please help…

Answer (score 2):

Put these two subs in a standard module and the run ***MakeButton***

```
Sub MakeButton()
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeOval, 228#, 557.25, 126.1, 126.1).Select
    With Selection
        .Characters.Text = "1 ADDER"
        .ShapeRange.Fill.Visible = msoTrue
        .ShapeRange.Fill.ForeColor.SchemeColor = 3
        .ShapeRange.Line.Visible = msoTrue
        .ShapeRange.Line.ForeColor.SchemeColor = 3
        .ShapeRange.Line.BackColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
        .Name = "MyButton"
        .OnAction = "whatever"
        .Top = Range("C3").Top
        .Left = Range("C3").Left
     End With
End Sub

Sub whatever()
    Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1).Value = 1
End Sub
```

To make the **Name** of the button *1 ADDER*, just update the line with *MyButton*

Comment: Would you please elaborate how to make a button in excel sheet whose name should be 1 ADDER and how to make it work....please add your little more help....